# Scala group Stream elements without evaluating the whole Stream

Tags: scala, stream, scala-streams

If I have a **Sorted** stream like this:

`Stream(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)`

How can group its content like this:

`Stream(List(1, 1), List(2, 2, 2), List(3), List(4, 4), List(5))`

Without causing the stream to be completely evaluated right away?

Comment: Stream(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5).groupBy(identity).values.map(_.toList)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this but it would only work for sorted streams

```
def groupValues(stream: Stream[Int]): Stream[List[Int]] = {
    if(stream.isEmpty) {
      Stream.empty
    } else {
      val head = stream.head
      val list = stream.takeWhile(_ == head).toList
      list #:: groupValues(stream.drop(list.size))
    }
  }
```